# self hosted ASP.NET core Web API with Kestrel using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I'm attempting to convert an old WCF service to an ASP.NET Core Web API, making use of the CoreWCF package. A key feature of this existing service is that it's being self hosted by an other application and is able to gracefully start & stop by button presses done by the users on a WPF UI.

This service should be accessed via an HTTPS endpoint and this is where I'm struggling. I have been able to succesfully access the API using regular HTTP, but I'm guessing I'm missing something or it's got something to do with my certificates. I've tried both using the default certificate by passing the `listeningOption.UseHTTPS()` but when I go to the URL, it'll return an error 500. I've also tried a self-signed certificate and passing it in the afformentioned method, but it keeps returning the same error.

The code for configuring everything looks like this:

Configuring the webhost:

```
private void CreateWebHostBuilder(){
    host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            options.ListenLocalhost(Startup.PORT_NR, 
                lOptions => lOptions.UseHttps("{absolute path}", "{password}"));
            );
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => { logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning); })
        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")
        .UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

Inside the `Startup` class:

Configuring the `IApplicationBuilder`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
    app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
    {
        // Add the Echo Service
        builder.AddService<EchoService>()                
        // Add service web endpoint                
        .AddServiceWebEndpoint<EchoService, IEchoService>(
            WEB_API_PATH,behavior => { behavior.HelpEnabled = true;}
        );
     });            
     app.UseMiddleware<SwaggerMiddleware>();            
     app.UseSwaggerUI();
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

Configuring the services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddServiceModelWebServices()                
            .AddHostedService<EchoService>()                       
            .AddSingleton(new SwaggerOptions())                  
            .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(); 
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.HttpsPort = HTTPS_PORT_NR;
            });           
}
```

Since this started as a WPF application, I don't have an appsettings.json file to add, and I wouldn't really know what to add in it if this were needed.

So if anyone has any suggestions or tutorial reference, be sure to let me know, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured out what was missing. I simply needed to add another endpoint, that would listen to https requests like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
    app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
    {
        // Add the Echo Service
        builder.AddService<EchoService>()                
        // Add service web endpoint                
        .AddServiceWebEndpoint<EchoService, IEchoService>(
            WEB_API_PATH,behavior => { behavior.HelpEnabled = true;}
        );
        .AddServiceWebEndpoint<EchoService, IEchoService>(new WebHttpBinding
        {
            Security = new WebHttpSecurity { Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport },
            WEB_API_PATH,behavior => { behavior.HelpEnabled = true;}
        );
     });
     // remainder of code.
}
```

Comment: Github repository to share, perhaps?